# Where is the new 3.2 Add::Curves::Hair menu?

Tags: interface, hair

In a 3.2 intro video about the new Add::Curves::Hair feature I see the menu items:

[image]

But when I looked in my own 3.2 install I don't see this:

[image]

Did the devs go hide it somewhere else or does it need to be enabled?  It is supposed to show in Object Mode, but I tried selecting an object and set to Edit and Sculpt mode but still no love.

Comment: Yes, the new hair system is still experimental and hidden in the development options. You need an Alpha version of Blender (3.2a or 3.3a) and enable it in preferences.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: This feature is ready to use in [Blender 3.3](https://www.blender.org/download/releases/3-3/).**

An archive of the original answer is below:

The Blender team is still actively developing the new curves datatype, an integral part of the new hair workflow. That's likely going to be a feature of Blender 3.3.

Feature tracker: https://developer.blender.org/T68981

Release notes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.3/Nodes_Physics

Official video: [The Future of Hair Grooming in Blender](https://youtu.be/6_USH9c_vNU)

Experimental versions: https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/

To enable the options in the Preferences:

1. select *Interface* and enable *Display > Developer Extras*
2. go to the *Experimental* tab that has appeared, and select *New Curve Tools* 
    [image: experimental section in the preferences]

Now you can add the new *Hair Curve* object and edit it in *Sculpt* mode.

[image: new hair curves]

Comment: Thanks so still a beta/alpha enabled feature.  I didn't see it in the 3.2 official release Experimental.

Comment: I'm on 3.2.1 stable and even if I enable Developer Extras, the Experimental tab only shows Debugging, no prototypes or new features.