# Poly modeling stylized but detailed/'frizzy' hair

Tags: modeling

All the tutorials I can find about making stylized hair are pretty much always just using curves - which works fine if you're just trying to shape out the most general form possible. But, it falls apart the second you start to try and model finer details, like smaller strands that fray.

[image]

This is for a different model, but a similar level of detail - using curves here just has things end up looking like limp fettucine.

[image]

I managed to pull off doing it with just straight poly modeling once, just extruding and splitting and moving verts, but it's much more work intensive than I would like and doesn't result in the *best* geometry.

I can't use sculpting because that's way too high poly to put into a game engine (plus it needs to be at least a little bit separated for physics), and as far as I know hair cards/particles are also more for realistic hair.

Does anyone know of any kind of workflow that could make this style of hair easier?

Comment: The hair system is undergoing a lot of work at the moment ready for Blender 3.3. See the answer in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268839/where-is-the-new-3-2-addcurveshair-menu and the [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_USH9c_vNU&t=724s) that the Blender dev team released recently.

Comment: I don't think the curves technique 'falls appart' if you need more detail. It just takes more time and work because you'll need more strands.